# Eclipse CDT Header Files inclusion Query

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I would like to include multiple header files placed in different folders in a single step other than Going in Properties-->Includes-->Add and linking each include folder of modules. C files are placed in different folders and tool takes all C files without any manual inclusion. Is there any possibility for header files. Thank you
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iIEx.png)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any possibility for header files

The short answer is no.

Header files and source files are different beasts and cannot be compared that way. C files can all be included because there is only one thing to do with them, compile them. But header files may be referenced from within C files in numerous different ways.

Consider a directory structure like this:

```
can/
   header.h
   can.c - has #include "header.h"
usa/
   header.h
   usa.c - has #include "header.h"
mex/
   mex.c - has #include "header.h"
```

In that case if the tool automatically added `can` and `usa` to include paths the behaviour would be incorrect.

Another case:

```
include/
   sys/
      bits.h
```

The tool needs to be told if `include/` should be on the include path, `include/sys` or neither.